# Issue with synching up coherence cache across servers

Tags: c#, .net, caching, oracle-coherence

I've a .net web application(A) hosted on server X that subscribes to coherence cache exposed by another .net application(B) hosted on server Y.
So ideally, at any point in time, cache in A and cache in B should be in sync.
In a situation, where A goes down for some reason(network error, server crash etc.), A will be restarted.
In the timespan when A is down, its possible that B cache could have some new updates.
So I want to make sure that A's cache is in sync with B's cache when its restarted.
What would be the best strategy to achieve this please?

Should A replicate its cache to a database(keys and values) on a continuous basis?
And when A goes down and is back up again, it can  check for the number of keys in its database.
If this count does not match with the count in B's cache, then it can repopulate its using B's cache?
Does this approach make sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Federated Caching](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/coherence/administer/replication.htm#COHAG5388) to have your caches synchronized across all your clusters.

Just keep in mind that if a replicated cache cluster for any reason has been restarted, you have **manually** (e.g. using JConsole) trigger data replication for this cluster when it got back. Otherwise, only newly cached data will be in sync.